# Object 'type' parsing on the Facebook PHP API

Tags: facebook-php-sdk

Important Information: Using the Facebook PHP API, Website has FULL permission to the user account when logged in, so this isn't a permission issue.

**The Problem**
So here is my problem. When parsing `/me/home` or another feed there are often times objects with types that would imply one thing, but then do not have any data associated with it.

Examples:
When two people become friends. Sometimes I will get an object that is declared as 'status' but contains no 'message' field. It actually contains no real information about the object at all other then the ID to the object, the ID and Name in the FROM section, a posted and updated time, and the 'type' variable. There is nothing as far as I can tell to inform me as to what type of 'status' object this is and how I should handle it. My idea then was to use the ID for the object, and request the details about the object specifically thinking perhaps i was only getting truncated information about it. The request for the specific object gives no additional information though.

Another example is links, I have received a object with a type of 'link' but the object it was saying was a link did not have a 'link' or 'source' field associated with it, or any other information really, and was about two people becoming friends.

Also, when viewing these feeds through the Graph API Explorer it actually omits these particular entries from its display all together.

**The Questions**

1. Is information about certain types of objects just not available?
2. Is there another way in which i need to get this information other then using `$facebook->api('/OBJECT_ID');`?
3. These are  not the only two situations where I am getting varying fields on things listed as the same type. Is there a reference guide somewhere for determining what A particular object is beyond using the type field?

Hope someone can shed some light on this subject.